# sending email with attachments in rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, smtp, actionmailer

I have followed the [Action Mailer Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html), but I still have the following problems:

1. I'm unable to send e-mail to a server outside my organization such as gmail
2. I'm unable to send attachments over size 195 **b**

Is there anything wrong, why are these problems occurring?

Answer (score 2):

please go through the rails casts episode [#206](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3) ... will help you..!!